Eloquent autocomplete in Laravel Sail
I have a project in Laravel Sail using Docker and VS Code. When I type, for example, User::where() this where does not appear as an autocomplete suggestion. Do you have a solution for this and other Eloquent methods?
I tried to install several PHP and Laravel extensions, but many give a problem of "I couldn't find the php command" (I think it's because I'm in a Docker environment or using WSL on Windows) or simply didn't solve the problem.

This question is similar to: Intellisense (autocompletion) for model in Laravel for Visual Studio Code or another IDE. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Primarily, I also think that the laravel-ide-helper package recommended by @N69S is the correct approach. Secondly, it is also possible to achieve what you want with PHPDoc. I previously had a question related to a similar hint extension: Expanding the PHPDoc of a PHP class

TLDR:
you can make your IDE's autocomplete work if you do User::query()->where() instead.
Details:
If you follow the runtime process of running the code User::where()
User extends the class \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
This class doesnt have a static method where() so the code land on the magic method __callStatic()
public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
{
    return (new static)->$method(...$parameters);
}

Which tries to call the non static method where(), but it doesnt exist so it land on the magic method __call()
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement', 'incrementQuietly', 'decrementQuietly'])) {
        return $this->$method(...$parameters);
    }

    if ($resolver = $this->relationResolver(static::class, $method)) {
        return $resolver($this);
    }

    if (Str::startsWith($method, 'through') &&
        method_exists($this, $relationMethod = Str::of($method)->after('through')->lcfirst()->toString())) {
        return $this->through($relationMethod);
    }

    return $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), $method, $parameters);
}

and end up running $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), $method, $parameters)
the method newQuery() return a \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder which contain the non static method where() and everything continues from here.
There is a static method present in the eloquent model that skips all the magic methods and returns a builder.
public static function query()
{
    return (new static)->newQuery();
}

So to make your IDE understand that you are using a builder, use the code User::query() first and you will get the hinting and auto complete

PS: To help with alias and laravel helpers, use laravel-ide-helper
